# How to get unique identifier of img tags in the DOM from MutationObserver?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

I am currently writing a Chrome extension which replaces all of the images on a web page with another, preselected image using a content script. This works pretty well, but the issue I am having with reactive 'lazy-loading' style sites is that images seem to exist as a placeholder but are not given a  `srcset` until they need one as the user is scrolling down the page.

This means that as the user scrolls down the page on a site like https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport, the images are the original images from the site, and not the image I gave them.

I am therefore trying to perform a man-in-the-middle operation where I set up a `MutationObserver` to watch the DOM for changes, and then catch changes to the `img` elements and either reverse/prevent them (ideally) or at least just put my desired image URLs back in the `src` & `srcset` attributes.

This is where I'm stuck - I'm not really sure how to achieve this, as there doesn't seem to be an obvious unique identifier for each image and so I can't figure out how to actually access the exact image I need to change. I have all of the images on the page stashed in an array, but no means of working out which one needs to change.

Here's the code that sets up a mutation observer and actually does the observing:

```
// Add Mutation Observer to listen for changes to the DOM tree

// Callback function for when DOM is changed

function mutationObserved (mutations, observer) {
  console.log(mutations);
};

// Create Observer with callback function and set it to observe the DOM

const observer = new MutationObserver(mutationObserved);
const observerConfig = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true, characterData: true, attributeOldValue: true, characterDataOldValue: true };
observer.observe(document, observerConfig);
```

As I scroll down the BBC Sport homepage with my Extension active, this produces the following output for a single MutationRecord:

[image]

And, when `target` is expanded:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Followed by a bunch of `on...` properties i.e. `onClick`, `onBlur` etc.

As you can see, it is hard to pick out a identifier here.

```
target: img.qa-lazyload-image.lazyautosizes.lazyloaded
```

is the `target` for all of the images.

I've tried simply re-running the extension on mutation of the DOM tree, and as you can imagine this just causes the extension to crash. I've also tried the following:

```
   for(const mutation of mutations) {
    
     if (mutation.attributeName === 'src') {
       // Do stuff...
     }
   }
```

inside the callback function, but this just results in no output.

Any help or guidance anyone could offer would be much appreciated. I don't know if I'm going about this the wrong way, or if there's some key bit of information I'm missing as I'm not very familiar with writing Chrome Extensions or HTML in general.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea why my images aren't rendering properly :/

Comment: Never mind, fixed them.

Comment: `target` is always referring to a specific node. Just because it _displays_ as `img.qa-lazyload-image.lazyautosizes.lazyloaded` in the console, does not mean that this is “all” images that would fit this selector.

Comment: Okay, so how do I get a reference to the unique node?

Comment: You _have_ it already, it’s called `target`.

Comment: Okay, great - so what would be the easiest way to access the node by that reference?

Comment: Loop over `mutations`, and then access the property of the MutationRecord - same as you would with _any other_ property …?